# php/ajax like button not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hi guys i try to create like button with php and ajax so write this codes but just work in first loop

```
<?php header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $("#like").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php  echo ADDRESS ;?>thank.php",
                    data: "like="+$("#like").val(),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#result").html(result);
                    }        
                });
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
<?php

foreach ($this->value['posts'] as $post){
    echo $post[1] . $post[0] .$post[2] . $post[3]  . '</br>';
    echo '<div id="result"></div>';
}
?>
```

I think the problem is in my #like that repeat and jquery dont know which one is our div

Comment: Ya, IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead. But then, really not sure what result you are expecting here

Comment: try use append(result)  instead of html(result)

Comment: @A.Wolff i used class but same result :(

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef not worked :-?

Comment: There is not enough info to know your issue. Inside `click` handler, `this` will refer to clicked element but then how do you want to target specific DIV `.result`. What is relation between `#like` and `#result` elements??? You would have better to provide all relevant code in question. Is there more than one `#like` button?

Comment: for each post there is one button !

Answer (score 0):

ok some one answered my question but id dont know why deleted :O

any way he or she writed

```
$(this)
```

thanks!

your code not worked but help me to fix that ok problem was in my button value ! all the buttons returned value for the first loop so i changed the js code to this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $(".like").click(function(){
                var spdiv = ".result" + $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php  echo ADDRESS ;?>thank.php",
                    data: "like="+$(this).val(),
                    success: function(result){
                        $(spdiv).html(result);
                    }        
                });
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
```

and i use class instead of id .

Answer (score 0):

IDs are Identifiers - meaning they must be unique! Also your script is messy and I guess you didn't mention there are many like buttons on the page, right?

Try this PHP code:

```
foreach ($this->value['posts'] as $index=>$post) {
    echo '<div class="comments">';
    echo $post[1] . $post[0] .$post[2] . $post[3]  . '</br>';
    echo '<button class="like" data-id="<?php echo $index; ?>">LIKE</button>';
    echo '<div class="result"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

And this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("div.comments").on("click", "button.like", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php  echo ADDRESS ;?>thank.php",
            data: {
                like: $(this).attr("data-id")
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $(this).siblings(".result").html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

The script above will add an event listener to all `buttons` that have the class `like`. The `$(this)` will refer to the like button and the `$(this).siblings(".result")` will get the result div that is a direct sibling of the like button(!), meaning they both sit in the same `<div class="comments">`.
I have changed the way you approach DOM elements. I also added a new identifier to your LIKE button so don't forget to change this `data-id` to suit your needs!